# How do I fit tensorflow ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've build my model, but do not know how to fit it. Could anyone give me some tip so I can use `ImageDataGenerator` in my models while working with images, or it is better to use other ways like using `Dataset`?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

# const
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH  = 150
BATCH = 32
EPOCHS = 5
train_dir = "data/images/train"
val_dir = "data/images/val"


# train image data generator
train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
train_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)
)

# validation image data generator
val_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=False
)
val_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory = val_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)
)

# count train cats & dogs
train_cats_len = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_dir, "cats")))
train_dogs_len = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(train_dir, "dogs")))
train_len = train_cats_len + train_dogs_len

# count validation cats & dogs
val_cats_len = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(val_dir, "cats")))
val_dogs_len = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(val_dir, "dogs")))
val_len = val_cats_len + val_dogs_len

# build a model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit?

# history = model.fit_generator(
#     train_generator,
#     steps_per_epoch=train_len // BATCH,
#     epochs=EPOCHS,
#     validation_data=val_generator,
#     validation_steps=val_len // BATCH,
#     verbose=True
# )

# raises error:
# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

My directory architecture:

```
data-
    |-images-
            |-train-
                   |-cats
                   |-dogs
            |-val-
                  |-cats
                  |-dogs
```

PS:

I found [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-data-generators-and-how-to-use-them-b69129ed779c) where same method used and everything seems to work, but not in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is you have the code

```
train_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)
```

You need to change that to

```
train_generator=train_generator.flow_from_directory( directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT)
```

do the same for the val_generator. In addition the default class_mode for the ImageDataGenerator is "categorical". Therefore in model.compile you should specify the loss as 'categorical_crossentropy'. In your model layer with the 2 nodes the activation function should be 'softmax'. As an aside I think your model may not perform very well as it may be a bit to simple to process the features of the data. I suggest adding several more convolutional layers with more filters. An example for a more complex model is shown below

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    epochs=15,
                    validation_steps=50,
                    verbose=2)
```

You can follow the example at the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/Course%202%20-%20Part%202%20-%20Lesson%202%20-%20Notebook.ipynb#scrollTo=Fb1_lgobv81m)